# Call Custom Jquery function onClick with multiple vars

Tags: jquery, smarty

In a smarty template I need to call a function when either 1 of 2 radio buttons is clicked.
This is what I have but it doesn't work.  I know for a fact that the code in the function itself does work as expected, I can't get the function to call however.

```
{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var shippingnotreqcheck = $("#shipping_notrequired");
            var shippingnotreqcheck2 = $("#shipping_notrequired2");

            shippingnotreqcheck.bind('click',
                $shippingisnotrequired);

            shippingnotreqcheck2.bind('click',
                $shippingisnotrequired);

            shippingisnotrequired = function() 
            {           
                    var billingcheck = 'checked';
                    $("#{/literal}{$Form->GetFieldInputName('shipping_matches_billing')}{literal}").attr('checked', 'checked');
                    $("#{/literal}{$Form->GetFieldInputName('shipping_matches_billing')}{literal}").addClass('disabled');
                    $("#{/literal}{$Form->GetFieldInputName('shipping_matches_billing')}{literal}").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }       
        });
    </script>
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.shippingisnotrequired` does not reference `jQuery.fn.shippingisnotrequired`.

---

Although I'd advise you against it, if you want to declare your function in the jQuery namespace, use this:

```
jQuery.shippingisnotrequired = function() 
{
    // The code here...
};
```

---

There's no reason for this to be in the jQuery namespace though. Just use a stand-alone function:

```
shippingnotreqcheck.bind('click', shippingisnotrequired);
shippingnotreqcheck2.bind('click', shippingisnotrequired);

function shippingisnotrequired () 
{
    // Code goes here...
}
```

Comment: "I am not JS programmer at all" --- what is this justification for? I'm not a building architect - so I don't build houses.

Comment: @zerkms - I tried holding down the mouse button on the up arrow for 15 seconds straight, but it only upvoted your comment once ;(